# Large triangular polygon with a large number of points in the mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, polygon, mesh

When creating the mesh, I had a problem: both in the game, and in the scene appears a large triangular polygon. The problem is that with a system size of 250 by 250 points there aren't this polygon. At a size of 400 by 400 points, it already appears.

What I did:

```
void Start () {
         MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
         Mesh mesh = mf.mesh;
         int size = 400;
         Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[size * size];
         Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[size * size];
         Vector2[] uvc = new Vector2[size * size];

         int c = 0;
         for (int i =0; i < size; i++)
         {
             for(int j =0; j < size; j++)
             {
                 vertices[c] = new Vector3(i, j, Mathf.Sin(j+i+Mathf.PI));
                 normals[c] = -Vector3.forward;
                 float mult = 1.0f / ((float)(size));
                 uvc[c] = new Vector2(((float)(i))*mult, ((float)(j)) * mult);
                 c++;
             }
         };

         int[] triangles = new int[(size-1)*(size-1)*6];
         int counter = 0;

         {
             for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
                 {
                     setTriangle(ref triangles, ref counter, i * size + j);
                     setTriangle(ref triangles, ref counter, (i + 1) * size + j);
                     setTriangle(ref triangles, ref counter, i * size + j + 1);

                     setTriangle(ref triangles, ref counter, (i + 1) * size + j);
                     setTriangle(ref triangles, ref counter, (i + 1) * size + j + 1);
                     setTriangle(ref triangles, ref counter, i * size + j + 1);

                 };
             }
         };

         mesh.Clear();
         mesh.vertices = vertices;
         mesh.triangles = triangles;
         mesh.normals = normals;
         mesh.uv = uvc;
         mesh.RecalculateNormals();

         gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(-55, -60, 90);

     void setTriangle(ref int[] triangle, ref int index, int num)
     {
         triangle[index++] = num;
     }
```

And what I have in results. The first picture is with 250 by 250 points. The second is with 400 by 400. The third is just bigger picture

[image: 250x250]
[image: 400x400]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over the max. number of vertices for the mesh when the size is 400x400.

The default max. number of vertices for a mesh is 65535. If you want to have more, then you have to set:

mesh.indexFormat = Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;

but this is not guaranteed to be supported in all platforms.

Comment: Thank you very much! This have solved all my problems. Now object scaling to the center and its center position is in a place that I've set.